# Show button in selected row of GridView and hide it in unselected rows

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, gridview

I have a button in `GridView` and i want to enable it only on the selected row and when i select a new row button should be invisible for previous row?

Comment: So basically you want to show the buttton in the SelectedRow and hide it in all others. Is the button in a TemplateField?

Comment: yes you are right button is in a template field

Comment: thank you for your answer Tim Schmelter bravo :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `GridView's` [`SelectedIndexChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selectedindexchanged%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) event to loop all rows and find your buttons. If it's the button in the `SelectedRow` show it, hide them otherwise:

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var grid = (GridView)sender;
    foreach (GridViewRow row in grid.Rows)
    {
        var btn = (Button)row.FindControl("Button1");
        // Compare this row with the currently selected row using the SelectedRow property
        // SelectedRow might be null, the logic would work anyway
        btn.Visible = row == grid.SelectedRow;
    }
}
```

Comment: if you don't require sorting try using ListView's SelectedItemTemplate

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by enabling the button in GridView.SelectedIndexChanged Event

But to disable the previous rows button you will have to iterate and disable them if the button is not in selected Row